# Ansible Tower/AWX multi credentials

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I have Ansible Tower running, I would like to be able to assign multiple credentials (ssh keys) to a job template and then when I run the job I would like it to use the correct credentials for the machine it connects to, thus not causing user lockouts as it cycles through the available credentials.

I have a job template and have added multiple credentials using custom credentials types, but how can I tell it to use the correct key for each host?

Thanks

Comment: This is really more because of how SSH works than because of a Tower job template.

Comment: sorry I dont think so. The issue is a single job with mutiple credentials and multiple hosts. i want the job to know which credential to use on which server and not cycle through them.

From what I can se you cannot map a credential to a host in any way

Answer (score 0):

I'm using community ansible so forgive if ansible tower behave differently

inventory.yml

```
all:
  children:
    web_servers:
      vars:
        ansible_user: www_user
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/www_rsa
      hosts:
        node1-www:
          ansible_host: 192.168.88.20
        node2-www:
          ansible_host: 192.168.88.21
    database_servers:
      vars:
        ansible_user: db_user
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/db_rsa
      hosts:
        node1-db:
          ansible_host: 192.168.88.20
        node2-db:
          ansible_host: 192.168.88.21
```

What you can see here is that:

- Both server are runing both webapp and db
- Webapp & DB uses different users to run
- Groups host names differ base on user (this is important)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Credential Types per Hosts and then create Credential per your credential types. you should transform injector configurations to host variables.

Please see the following post:

> https://faun.pub/lets-do-devops-ansible-awx-tower-authentication-power-user-2d4c3c68ca9e